# Rails 4.0.0 errors in controller: ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hi I got this error in my Controller:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound in CoursesController#create_course
Invalid single-table inheritance type: CourseTemplate is not a subclass of Course
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
course = Course.new(self.attributes)
```

what can I do to fix this ?

I've allready tried to do this in model:

```
self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
```

But then I got this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `course_objects`
```

This error appears becaus the ID of the course_object is tried to use again, id is the PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the id from the old object attributes:

```
obj_attributes = self.attributes
obj_attributes.delete("id") 
course = Course.new(obj_attributes)
```

Comment: Dosn't change anyhing, got the same error as well ... do I need this: `self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled` at the moment don't have it

Comment: If I add this: `self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled` in model and your code then I got this error: Mysql2::Error: Table 'xyz_dev.clients_course_objects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `clients_course_objects` .... in this line: ` @course.clients << @lecturer.client` . ... the problem is the I have tables clients_courses, and course_objects -> but before I migrated to 4.0.0 it worked fine